# How to use Inputstream with Handler

Tags: java, android

I don't understand how should I work with Inputstream and Handler.

I hope someone could explain it. I read some tutorials and I understood what they do but not how they do it.

Here is an example I don't understand:

```
   public void run() {
    int ret = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16384]; 
    int i;

    while (true) { // read data
        try {
            ret = mInputStream.read(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }

        i = 0;
        while (i &lt; ret) {
            int len = ret - i;
            if (len &gt;= 1) {
                Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler);
                int value = (int)buffer[i];
                // &amp;squot;f&amp;squot; is the flag, use for your own logic
                // value is the value from the arduino
                m.obj = new ValueMsg(&amp;squot;f&amp;squot;, value);
                mHandler.sendMessage(m);
            }
            i += 1; // number of bytes sent from arduino
        }

    }
   }
    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg) msg.obj;
        // this is where you handle the data you sent. You get it by calling the      getReading() function
        mResponseField.setText(&quot;Flag: &quot;+t.getFlag()+&quot;; Reading: &quot;+t.getReading()+&quot;; Date: &quot;+(new Date().toString()));
    }
};
```

Sorry for my English

Comment: You're not actually explaining what part of it you don't understand... please elaborate your question.

Comment: I recive all the time data from the accessory. I don`t know how I can handle this.

Comment: Do you receive the data inside your `handleMessage` method?

Comment: This is just an example from a site. I try to understand this for my app.

Comment: Yes, but what part don't you understand?

Comment: I hope you can understand me, my English isnt well.

Comment: I'll try again: what part of the code don't you understand? :-)

Comment: Sorry i press enter i hate this...First i don't understand why he make such a big Bytearray he can get max 8 Byte from read() or? What does Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler) do? How can i send the value from Array to the main activity textview?

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer - hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to answer your questions both in the question and in the comments.

**Firstly:** calling `read()` on the `InputStream` with a `byte[]` will read bytes into the buffer.

```
byte[] myBuffer = new byte[16384];
myInputStream.read(myBuffer);
```

This code will read bytes from the `inputstream` and store it in the `byte[]` called `myBuffer`. It's not reading from the buffer.

Check out the documentation for the `InputStream` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29), or:

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b.

**Secondly:**

What the code does (without seeing the rest of the code), is that it starts reading the `inputstream` on a background thread. It will read a byte each time here:

```
ret = mInputStream.read(buffer);
```

To be able to change views from a background thread, we will need some kind of mechanism to make a bridge between the background thread and the UI thread, because only the UI thread can change views.

In comes the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) :-)

Quote taken from the `Handler` documentation:

> [...] to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

In your code, you therefore "obtain" the current `Handler` associated with your UI thread:

```
Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler); // Obtain the UI thread handler.
int value = (int)buffer[i]; // Read data.
m.obj = new ValueMsg(&amp;squot;f&amp;squot;, value); // Create a message to send to the UI thread handler.
mHandler.sendMessage(m); // Send the message to the UI thread handler.
```

After that the UI thread `Handler` receives the message inside the `handleMessage` method:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg) msg.obj;
        // this is where you handle the data you sent. You get it by calling the      getReading() function
        mResponseField.setText(&quot;Flag: &quot;+t.getFlag()+&quot;; Reading: &quot;+t.getReading()+&quot;; Date: &quot;+(new Date().toString()));
    }
```

and acts accordingly to the message received and displays the message in your `TextView` of choice.

`Handlers` are somewhat of a complex topic, but is needed in many places, when you start using multiple threads and most apps would at some point start using multiple threads :-)

**On a sidenote**

It's possible to use something else, but the handler.

Inside your while-loop, that sends the `message` to the UI `Handler` you could replace the `Handler` code with the convenience method called `runOnUiThread(runnable)` so your code could look something like this:

```
while (i < ret) {
    int len = ret - i;
    if (len >= 1) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            int value = (int)buffer[i];
            mResponseField.setText(String.valueOf(value));                   
        });
    }
    i += 1; // number of bytes sent from arduino
}
```

Bear in mind, that the above code might not compile (I haven't tried it out myself...). You would have to be in an `Activity` or a `Fragment`, because the `runOnUiThread` method is bound to the `Activity` class. Also some fields would probably have to be `final` to read them from the `runOnUiThread` method, but I hope you get the point :-)

Hope this helps - else let me know and I'll try to elaborate :-)

Comment: Phew - got tired just looking at all of that :)